# how to save a file and not throw exception errors

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have the following code that works well when I save the file. However when the save "to dialog box opens with the "save" or "cancel" option.....When I click Cancel I get and exception error here.
 W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(1).ToString) How would I fix this? I have tried this but don't get anywhere with it.

```
 If result <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Close()
    End If

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result As DialogResult

    'Writes txt File to C: Drive
    SaveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = ("C:\")
    SaveFileDialog1.FileName = ("Save As...")
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = ("Only Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt")
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

           Dim W As New IO.StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, True)  ' writes specified information to save file
    W.WriteLine(lblTimeDate.Text & "             " & txtJobFileName.Text)
    W.WriteLine() 'Writes Blank Line
    W.WriteLine()

    'Formats Write to save file       
    W.WriteLine(vbTab & gradesListBox.Items(0).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(1).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(2).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(3).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(4).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(6).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(9).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(7).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(8).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(9).ToString)
    W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(10).ToString)
    W.WriteLine()
    W.WriteLine()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
  '  do all that stuff


End If
```

Oddly, you have a dialog result variable, but didnt use it.  You dont need to specify each item in the listbox (it would get rather tedious when there were hundreds of items):

```
 For n as integer=0 to gradesListBox.items.count-1
     W.WriteLine(gradesListBox.Items(n).ToString)
 next n
```

Comment: That was a very simple fix, thanks. I have another question but will save for another time